# Customise flash message of Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm using Sonata admin in my Symfony project. Users are stored in **User** entity and I have provided provision for users to manage their user details as their profile. When the profile is updated, the flash message looks like,

[image]

but the message looks odd to me. How can I change this message to something like **Profile updated successfully**? Is it possible to handle **User** related flash messages from **UserAdmin** class?

Any suggestion/solution will be helpful. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overrided the translation file to change the flash messages which is common to all entity actions.

I just copied **SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff** file from

**/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/translations/**

and placed it in either **src/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/translations** or **/translations** and edit the messages as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in CrudController, when the update action is successful, for every entity, this code is run : https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/src/Controller/CRUDController.php#L357 :

```
                $this->addFlash(
                    'sonata_flash_success',
                    $this->trans(
                        'flash_edit_success',
                        ['%name%' => $this->escapeHtml($this->admin->toString($existingObject))],
                        'SonataAdminBundle'
                    )
                );
```

**So if you want to overide it** :

**Solution 1** : 
You change de translation for every entities...

**Solution 2**:
You overide this flash message in using your own controller specific to UserEntity...

*If I was you, I'll create a baseController, in order to make this translation customizable, and every entity will herit from this....*

**UPDATE** :

In the baseController, you override each actions (create, delete, edit).
After you've got the choise, the first : you create a custom action, the second, you create a protected variable for translation message ...

```
class OwnBaseController extends BaseController {
  ....

  protected $successMessage = "flash_edit_success";
  protected $errorMessage = "flash_edit_error";

  ....

  /** Exemple with edit action **/

                try {
                    $existingObject = $this->admin->update($submittedObject);
                    if ($this->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                        return $this->renderJson([
                            'result' => 'ok',
                            'objectId' => $objectId,
                            'objectName' => $this->escapeHtml($this->admin->toString($existingObject)),
                        ], 200, []);
                    }
                    $this->addFlash(
                        'sonata_flash_success',
                        $this->successMessage ,    // <----- LOOK HERE
                            'messages'
                        )
                    );
                    // redirect to edit mode
                    return $this->redirectTo($existingObject);
                } catch (ModelManagerException $e) {
                    $this->handleModelManagerException($e);
                    $isFormValid = false;
                } catch (LockException $e) {
                    $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_error', $this->trans($this->errorMessage, [  // <----- LOOK HERE
                        '%name%' => $this->escapeHtml($this->admin->toString($existingObject)),
                        '%link_start%' => '<a href="'.$this->admin->generateObjectUrl('edit', $existingObject).'">',
                        '%link_end%' => '</a>',
                    ], 'SonataAdminBundle'));
                }


class UserController extends OwnBaseController {
   protected $successMessage = "user_edit_success_custom_message";
   protected $errorMessage = "user_edit_error_custom_message";

}
```

Comment: Can you suggest what must be implemented in baseController? Override EditAction??